# How to get plugins by setting a path

Tags: mef

I created console c# project. and in the code I have made a module. My code looks like this.

```
[Import]
public IMessageSender MessageSender { get; set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.Run();
}

public void Run()
{
    Compose();
    Console.ReadLine(MessageSender.Send("Message Sent"));
}

private void Compose()
{
    AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}

public interface IMessageSender
{
    string Send(string message);
}

[Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]
public class EmailSender : IMessageSender
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine. But now I added a new project in my solution and added module into that
AnotherProject->EmailSender.cs

```
[Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]
public class EmailSender : IMessageSender
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Now in the main console program I changed some of my code.

```
private void Compose()
{
    var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
    //AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

But now when I run this program. It doesnt load the module. MessageSender in main program is null. What wrong I have done.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to check:

1. Have you correctly referenced the assemblies?
2. The `DirectoryCatalog` by default uses the search pattern `*.dll`. Because you have a console application, which uses the `.exe` extension, no exports in that assembly will get picked up by the `DirectoryCatalog` - with the default search pattern. You'll likely want to use an `AggregateCatalog`, passing in the `DirectoryCatalog` (`*.dll`), and either another `DirectoryCatalog` (`*.exe`), or an `AssemblyCatalog`, of the entry assembly.
3. You currently have one `[Import]` where you may end up with multiple `[Export(typeof(IMessageSender))]`, you didn't state that you have *moved* the `EmailSender` to the class library, merely that you have created a *new* one, which means you'll likely end up with a cardinality mismatch where it is expecting a sinple import, you have many exports. This will explicitly throw an exception, which is what will happen even it couldn't find a single instance of `IMessageSender`, because your `[Import]` attribute is not set to allow a default value where no part can be provided. If you need to be fault tollerant, you can use `[Import(AllowDefault = true)]`

Incidentally... the above code won't compile, I assume it was just an example and not a copy-paste from your current code?

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    return message;
}
```

You're retuning a message to a `void` method - that can't be done, and it also means that `EmailSender` doesn't correctly implement `IMessageSender`. Not too bothered, as I think it is an example more than actual code.

Comment: everything is done correctly, that void in plugin is a typing mistake. it is string. and I am not doing ImportMany because i know that i will have only one module for this application. I think I need to add *.dll in directory catalog. May be that will work.